# How to call a function after click function execute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using click event to execute some code. And after execute the click function code, want to execute another function or code like a callback function. But have struct to call function after the click function.

```js
var $body = jQuery('body');

$body.on('click', '.modal_popup_btn', function() {
    var $data_type = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-link');

    jQuery('.modal_wrapper[data-popup="'+ $data_type +'"]').removeClass('modal_closed').addClass('modal_opened');
    jQuery('.modal_wrapper[data-popup="'+ $data_type +'"]').find('.modal_container').removeClass('modal_container_closed').addClass('modal_container_opened');
    setTimeout(function() {
      hiddenBodyScrollWithPadding();
    }, 550);
  });
```

Here is the code, need to call 'hiddenBodyScrollWithPadding()' after the click code execute. Here used setTimeout to execute before code. But setTimeout is a bad idea to this situation. Can anyone have another idea to execute this function in a better way?

Comment: Is your Modal animating (like FadeIn) while clicking on '.modal_popup_btn'? And Do you want to execute 'hiddenBodyScrollWithPadding()' function after Modal animation is complete?

Comment: why don't you let your function execute in the normal flow at the end?

Comment: Your code works, your `hiddenBodyScrollWithPadding` function is called after each click event.

Comment: @giuseppedeponte please read the question well! he is not saying its not working, he is looking for a better solution.

Comment: Agreed, why not just execute the function normally? What was the reason for using a timeout originally?

Comment: @Muhammad Yes, you are right. What I meant was his code works without using setTimeout (which is a bad solution).

Comment: I think you're doing it right, you just need to set the time in `setTimeout` exact the same as your animation duration. i also curious if there's a better solution

Comment: @ADyson - If i used the function normally the body scroll visible before the animation complete stage. Its little messy to visible.

Comment: @Sou - if network is slow then hiddenBodyScroll function is execute with time manner before the code execute. That's my worry to use setTimeout here.

Comment: @Umapathi: I didn't see any network call, i think the only affects is the animation duration, did you use CSS animation? cause there is `addClass` call

Comment: @Umapathi how and where are you defining the animation? I don't think you've provided all the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If your '.modal_wrapper' animating, then add this jQuery Code.. Your Popup modal will listen `transition` event is ended then check if Modal has `.modal_opened` class. If transition has been ended and `hasClass` condition is true then your custom function will be executed.

```
jQuery('.modal_wrapper').on('transitionend', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(jQuery(this).hasClass('modal_opened')){
        hiddenBodyScrollWithPadding();
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans. Above code is not giving exact result.